# Unable to debug React.js code in visual studio code

Tags: reactjs, debugging, webpack, visual-studio-code, source-maps

I have express backend and react js on front end. I want to debug react code with visual studio code and im getting grayed out breakpoint with message
"Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)".

My bundled file and source map file is located in public folder. In chrome my project structure looks like this

[image: chrome project structure]

I have installed debugger for chrome extension for visual studio code. 
My launch.json configuration is

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/public",
            "trace": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch index.html (disable sourcemaps)",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
        },
    ]
}
```

Webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    app: "./public/javascripts/app.jsx"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    devtoolLineToLine: true,
    path: __dirname + "/public",
    pathinfo: true,
    sourceMapFilename: "./app.js.map",
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["react"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  watch: true
};
```

And this is my project structure:

[image: My project structure]

Please explain to me what am i doing wrong.
Any help is well appreciated!

Comment: What files are you trying to  set breakpoints on that are generating this error?

Comment: Can you try removing the `/public` from your webRoot? And, can you include the output of the `.scripts` command in your question?

Comment: @PaulMcloughlin File that i am trying to debug is app.jsx. React file.

Answer (score 2):

1. try run "npm start" in terminal first.
2. when app started, start chrome debug

it worked for me

this is my launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Running `npm start` made me realize that I had the frontend docker container running (in the same port) so most likely this the reason why the debugger didn't work. Stopping the container, running `npm start` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Re. VSC's extension, it would be better to first update the Debugger for Chrome extension. Your launch.json config file should read versio 0.2.0.
Then is your VSC up to date too? There was a bug in VSC 1.21.* who could be responsible for that. Check if it still there after updating to 1.23.